# Pascal basic, need some explanation

Tags: pascal

Recently i just started learn pascal then i found this code

```
function mengkono(s: integer):integer;
begin
  if s < 3 then
    mengkono := 3*s+1
  else
    mengkono := mengkono(s-1) + megnkono(s-2);
end;

begin
  writeln(mengkono(6));
  readln;
end.
```

the thing that confused me is this line

```
else
  mengkono := mengkono(s-1) + mengkono(s-2);
```

from the code above, it's output is 47. Because the input is 6 and 6 is greater than 3 so the line above is ran. Can someone explain to me how it works? i still confused.

Comment: As others have said, it's a *recursive function* (which you can Google to learn more about) which calls itself. How does it stop calling itself? What keeps it from recursing infinitely until the stack is consumed and there's a fault? That's the important part: there needs to be a condition of inputs under which it will  return a value without calling itself. That condition, in this case, is when `s < 3`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive function. A function that calls to itself.

If the input is 6 then first it'll do 
       megnkono:=megnkono(5)+megnkono(4)

then you need to caclulate megnkono(5) and megnkono(4)
for 5 it'll be 
         megnkono:=megnkono(4)+megnkono(3)
then you need to caclulate megnkono(4) and megnkono(3)

and so on... (pay attention when input is <3 is just giving a direct result)

Answer (score 1):

The function is a recursive function, i.e. it calls itself (the line that confuses you). Every time that line executes, `s` is slightly smaller and eventually it goes below 3 which stops the recursion.